# Android: Live character count for EditText

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a character count of an EditText (numberRoom). When user would insert 8 characters button should switch from state Disabled and color 0xBBFFFFFF to state Enabled and color 0xFFFFFFFF.
I've tried few method and I think the best one I've found is that one below. However button has state Enabled and color 0xFFFFFFFF even when input is empty. What's wrong there?

```
public class Join_room_screen extends Activity {

    EditText numberRoom;
    Button goToRoom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.joinroom);

        numberRoom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.roomNumber);
        goToRoom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goToRoom);

        TextWatcher watcher = new LocalTextWatcher();
        goToRoom.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        updateButtonState();
    }

    void updateButtonState() {
        boolean enabled = checkEditText(numberRoom);
        goToRoom.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        goToRoom.setEnabled(enabled);
    }

    private boolean checkEditText(EditText edit) {
        return ((edit.getText().toString()).length() == 8 );
    }

    private class LocalTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            updateButtonState();
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    }


}
```

However in properties I've

Comment: in onCreate()
add this.. 
 goToRoom.setEnabled(false);

Comment: Crosspost: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/74930/29371

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function the enabled variable is never used so the background colour and enabled states are always set.

```
void updateButtonState() {
    boolean enabled = checkEditText(numberRoom);
    goToRoom.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    goToRoom.setEnabled(enabled);
}
```

I would replace with something like

```
void updateButtonState() {
    boolean enabled = checkEditText(numberRoom);
    if (enabled) {
        goToRoom.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        goToRoom.setEnabled(enabled);
    } else {
        //change them back to disabled state
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed to this
`void updateButtonState() {
        boolean enabled = checkEditText(numberRoom);
        if (enabled) {
            goToRoom.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            goToRoom.setEnabled(enabled);
        } else {
            goToRoom.setBackgroundColor(0xBBFFFFFF);
            goToRoom.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }`

and button is disabled, however when I entry 8 characters it's still disabled.

Comment: So this was the cause of the problem outlined in the question. If you want a general code check rather than an answer to a specific problem then you should probably post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have one problem in updateButtonState(), it always sets one color to your button. I see, you have already solved that.
The other problem is that you set TextChangeListener not to an EditText, but somewhy to a Button.
The EditText should be watched.

```
numberRoom.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

instead of

```
goToRoom.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Comment: But numberRoom is EditText, not goToRoom

Comment: Right. And it's the right object to watch for text changes. Look, your code tries to watch your button's text change